# Temporary Storage in FireFox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, storage

I've developed an extension that creates alot* of data during a browsing session.  Think, 2 to 3 times the total HTTP traffic (images, HTML, etc.).

Currently I'm just stashing all of this in a Javascript variable, but this obviously isn't tenable if the extension is going to get any serious usage.

So, the question is, where should I stash this data?  Its very rarely accessed, but when it is ALL of it is.  Additionally, it'd be nice if the data **doesn't** persist beyond the current session; stale data is useless in this case, and I'd rather not fill up disk needlessly.

<sub>*For something running in a browser, in Javascript</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly standard solution is to use local files as storage. Code running as a Firefox extension has sufficient privileges to read and write local files. The [MDC File I/O code snippets page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO) is a very good starting point for understanding and implementing this in your extension. It also shows you how to [find your extension's directory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO#Getting_your_extension%27s_folder) and illustrates the mechanism for [creating temporary files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO#Creating_temporary_files).

These approaches should give you the tools you need to do what you're after. Let us know if you need further questions.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the database that comes with Firefox 3.5.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Storage

Answer (score 0):

On the disk. You wouldn't be able to keep it all in memory anyway if it's indeed 3x the traffic. You can always delete the no-longer-needed data at shutdown and/or at the start of the next session.

The specific way to store the data depends on the specific requirements you have - what you need to store, what is the patterns in the data access. If, as you say, you just need to save individual files received, I'd store them as files.